# How can I call service class when database is not empty

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

*How can I check if the cursor is empty or if there are any contacts in the contact list of the phone?*
*When database is not empty then it call my Shake Service class but this logic does not works*

```
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM details", null);
    Boolean rowExists;

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
           Intent i_startservice = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShakeService.class);
           startService(i_startservice);
           rowExists = true;

    } else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Databse is Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rowExists = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background services will no longer be implementable after Android O. So, please check with the documentation about Foreground Services before you proceed.
Happy hacking!

Comment: No no, I am not doing this for hacking. Actually I have semester project in which I am making an application in that whenever you shake your phone a phone call will proceed to your guardian but it wouldn't run not home page because of empty data...So whenever database is empty it show an toast message, but it crush my application